# rjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException on startActivity(intent,bundle animantion)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi I am using following code but sometimes app is crashing with  error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException  in   startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
       Bundle bndlanimation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out).toBundle();
       startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);
     } else
       startActivity(slideactivity);
       finish();
```

Here is the crash logs

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 1  at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1553) 2   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499) 3   at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManager‌​Native.java:4465)
>   4 at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5361) 5   at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:37‌​70) 6   at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4003) 7  at
>   com.tapcibo.tapcibo.uifragment.LaunchActivity.a(SourceFile:1‌​05)

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: 0java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
1 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1553)
2 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
3 at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:4465)
4 at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5361)
5 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3770)
6 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4003)
7 at com.tapcibo.tapcibo.uifragment.LaunchActivity.a(SourceFile:105)

Comment: @RahulDevanavar - could you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `ActivityOptionsCompat` instead of `ActivityOptions` if you are using `ActivityCompat.startActivity()`.
As well use `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` to make animation options.

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem, after digging really deep I saw that there is some problem with the SDK > 21 so lollipop up. In my case this happens when using transparent theme together with some enter and exit transitions.

Two options:

If I remove the ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation().toBundle(); and work good again.

If I set my theme to my app normal theme works good too.

I will have to investigate further but I guess there is some configuration on the theme that makes this crash.

Comment: Hello have you found the solution? I am facing the same problem and having trouble with it. The thing is, I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light and not transparent themes, I am also using ActivityCompatOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation and it presents the same problem

Comment: hi! I am also using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, but have same issue. any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);
```

use

```
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, slideactivity, bndlanimation)
```

Comment: any specific reason why to use ActivityCompat

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm using the ActivityCompat

Comment: Crashes randomly on using `ActivityCompat.startActivity`.. Has anybody found any workaround for this? Clearly its some android bug.

Comment: It crashes randomly for me as well when I use ActivityCompat.startActivity and I have a transparent theme