# IllegalArgumentException on startActivity with bundle

Tags: android, kotlin

Getting an IllegalArgumentException when starting an activity with a bundle like this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, IntroActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in_activity, R.anim.fade_out_activity).toBundle()
startActivity(intent, bundle)
```

The main problem is that this doesn't occur on all devices. So far, from 100+ devices, got it on around 20 or so.

I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1722)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1671)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerProxy.java:5573)
       at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:6151)
       at android.app.Activity.cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition(Activity.java:4440)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4417)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4691)
       at [...].splash.SplashActivity.continueToIntro(SplashActivity.java:428)
```

I saw a similar question here: [rjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException on startActivity(intent,bundle animantion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026745/rjava-lang-illegalargumentexception-on-startactivityintent-bundle-animantion)
But unfortunately I am already using ActivityOptionsCompat.

It's happening on Android api 23+.

Did anyone get this and did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Those seem like an unusual set of flags to put on an `Intent`. What is your objective behind those flags?

Comment: Which one does `intent.flags` refer to? IMHO, you might need to use `addFlags` instead of `setFlags`.

Comment: Never thought that the problem was from the flags, tbh. The flags needed are probably just these: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as i'm trying to clear all the stack of activities so the user can't press back and get to the previous one.

Comment: Im im currently facing the same Error. Does it help to change that Flags?

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308198/start-new-activity-and-finish-current-one-in-android you can disable a history on that activity